# Why calling the function isn't ambiguous in SFINAE?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I am using SFINAE to check whether some class has 'print()' function or not. The code works but why calling `has_print()` is not ambiguous?

```
class cls {
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "some text" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
auto has_print(T tt) -> decltype(T().print(), std::true_type()) {
    tt.print();
    return std::true_type();
}

std::false_type has_print(...) {
    std::cout << "Doesn't contain print()" << std::endl;
    return std::false_type();
}

int main() {
    cls c;
    has_print(c);

    return 0;
}
```

It could match both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It could match both of them.

In [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences), the 1st overload wins the 2nd one which takes ellipsis parameter.

> 1. A standard conversion sequence is always better than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence.

Comment: Can you tell me please, what is the difference between "standard conversion" and "user-defined conversion"?

Comment: @Kanony See [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) and their [ranks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences). BTW given `has_print(c);`, for the 1st overload to be called, the standard conversion sequence required is qualified as *exact match*; anyway whatever the conversion is required the standard conversion and even user-defined conversion is better than ellipsis conversion.